# simple redirect from one page to another in web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, http-redirect

I'm using Asp.Net web forms with IIS 8.5.

I already have **url routing** in place and setup **httperrors** in `web.config` to catch 404/500 errors, but I now need to redirect some old pages to a new destination.

The **old page will no longer exist**, so it must not be caught by the `HttpErrors` code before it can be redirected.

I want to redirect a page from `/widgets/oldwidget` to `/newwidget`

Note: `/newwidget` is the rerouted url, the physical page will be something like: `/pages/oldwidget.aspx`.

I'm struggling difficult to find clear instructions as to how to use `httpdirect` in this scenario.

Anyone offer any advice? Is this the right approach?

```
 <httpRedirect enabled="false" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" exactDestination="true">
     // Redirect my page
 </httpRedirect>

<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly">
    <clear/>
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1"/>
    <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" path="/404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    <error statusCode="500" path="/500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

Comment: Do you use webforms or MVC?

Comment: Please consider using IIS URL Rewrite to redirect those non-existing URLs to new ones. 404/500 should be kept unchanged for simplicity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use url rewrite to achieve your requirement.

You could install the url rewrite extension on this [url](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

Then you could add below config setting in the config file.

```
<system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - do I create a new rule for every url or just add another match/action?

Comment: In my opinion, this is based on your requirement. If you could generate a regex that match all your requirement, there is no need to create a rule for every url. If you couldn't generate the regex, I suggest you could create a new rule for every url.